# Regex replacement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, replace

I have a table where a particular string field often includes unicode for single and double quotes inside of it: `\u0027` and `\u0022` respectively. So it turns out, I actually need them escaped even more. I need to put an extra `\` in front of them.

For example, I need to change `\u0027Hello, world\u0027` to `\\u0027Hello, world\\u0027`

What kind of SQL could perform this kind of an update on the table for all records?

Comment: FWIW I'm using postgresql. Bonus points if you can also show me how to force all inserts and updates to afterwards perform the same modification, without ending up with three slashes.

Comment: You're better off storing the values in the database in Unicode and perform the escaping as and when needed - it'll be less complex at the end of the day.

Comment: This sounds really suspect to me. Why do you “need” to have encoded data in the database? This usually implies the code putting the data in or getting it back out has some serious problems. Data should normally be kept in raw unescaped text format.

Comment: @will I'm allowed to mess with the db, but not with any of the software that retrieves and handles the data. I'm aware it has serious problems, but it's sadly not in my power to fix those problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really need this, then you can use such RE:

```
UPDATE table SET c = regexp_replace(c, '[^\\]\\(u\d{4})', '\\\\\1', 'g');
```

Make sure that standard_conforming_strings is enabled and regex_flavor is set to advanced.

```
SHOW standard_conforming_strings;
 standard_conforming_strings 
-----------------------------
 on
(1 row)
```

Replacement string `'\\\\\1'` means two following backslashes `\\` and `\1` represent first (reporting) parenthesized subexpression (that is, `'u'` concatenated with four digits from pattern).

Comment: Thanks. I made two variants of this: one to handle a string beginning with a unicode escape sequence, and another that will preserve the character preceding the \u (the version you provide consumes it). I also had to double the number of backslashes since our db doesn't use standard_conforming_strings. Icky stuff, but it worked.

Comment: @Dan: You can also use dollar quoting $$pattern$$ to avoid that doubled backslashes http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Answer (score 1):

An UPDATE statement with `SET yourcolumn = REPLACE(yourcolumn, '\u0027', '\\u0027')` ought to do it.  Try the below first to check that it works before doing a mass update.

```
SELECT REPLACE('\u0027', '\u0027', '\\u0027')
```

Comment: +1 This does look useful, but it appears it is incapable of detecting whether or not the double-escape is already performed.

Comment: ...and therein lies the problem, Dan - please take a moment to seriously consider storing the data in a more appropriate format.